# New Google reCAPTCHA keeps failing to verify with localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, web, captcha

New Google reCAPTCHA
Using CodeIgniter 2.2.2
Everytime I try to run my test, it returns a false result after loading for a long time with the following warning message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:
>   file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=PUBLICKEY&response=03AHJ_VuvOwCxIKqGoZXeEOWvDxMjYrBsH9HyWpbxg1YmBTThs8gINjC5yEQOG0fVikDPY3GXemQVrB6DT965o0LARL2rRDP-U6m9Y9DSFdDvz55vwsewe4--m0NfssykJZ3et6zItKH7mNsDIi1LLtPrn7vaQmCGlK3LW2hS4Q8TMDhjTW-tecmCRbonCcTcvMN4gHnWuGzSzUFUlOPxAlSHEvkBHspZb5SnGLNakZ5rrF591LL9SS8NrZErFVO3EySpW_CCG26uDhpMJW5y5B_3nZnBYZqpmf0eIIMy5w3rk2FjJrPw2G8Kj98Cv1B1xJcXBgML7uCnZRmc7WDZhzFoI2JAeuEBNwQkQJvSGXsGLGkewz1ClPiQwzYZRlwEpgo2Zpkri6lrIlNMIc0dtmhM7U172LGELgjbNKFAW29Aq8wTOCwC2tztWlTn_8mq9SrS_mhhs7iaG&remoteip=127.0.0.1):
>   failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond.
>
> Filename: controllers/cap.php

Here is my html code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form action="validation" method="post">

      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input name="name" required><br />

      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input name="email" type="email" required><br />

      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My_Public_Key"></div>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>

    <!--js-->
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my php file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class cap extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('users_model', 'user');
        $this->lang->load("message",$this->session->userdata('language'));
    }
  public function index() {

    $this->load->view("cap");
  }
    public function validation()
    {
        $email;$comment;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
          $email=$_POST['email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
          $email=$_POST['comment'];
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
        remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=MyPrivateKey&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);

        if($response['success'] == false)
        {
          echo '<h2>Wrong</h2>';
        }else
        {
          echo '<h2>Correct</h2>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

(Of course I generated my public and private key through google api webpage)

Any idea guys? Do I need to turn on curl or something in my php?

Comment: Check your php.ini settings and ensure that `allow_url_fopen = On` is there somewhere

Comment: How would i achieve this if I am on a real web hosting server?

Comment: On CentOS, look at the file `/etc/php.ini`. If the server runs Ubuntu, check `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Most likely this is turned to `Off` if this is a real web server (and if it's shared hosting you can't change that). You should really use cURL for this

Comment: Can you provide me an example of using cURL and merge it with my code above?

Comment: Let me post an example as a response since I can't style it in a comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible that `allow_url_fopen = Off` in your `php.ini`, preventing `file_get_contents` from opening URLs.

You could just use cURL for this, something like this:

```
    $fields = array(
        'secret'    =>  "MySecretKey",
        'response'  =>  $captcha,
        'remoteip'  =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: It says my CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is undefine

Comment: The only way for `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to be undefined would be for you to be using a version of PHP older than 4.0.2, which is REALLY unlikely. Is this a PHP Notice or PHP Warning?

Comment: It is loading for a long time as it looks like it is getting a timeout on the other side of the server.

Comment: curl response is:Curl Error :--Connection timed out after 3011 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an issue with the config cache.

Try to run `php artisan config:clear` in laravel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).